# problem : Azure Logic App is not visible in Azure API management

Tags: azure-api-management

I am facing one issue. I am not able to find logic app in API management application.

I am 10 different workflows with HTTP trigger. Through Postman, they are working fine.

Both apps (logic app and API management app) are under same subscription and resource group. but when I am searching logic app it is not visible.

In API management ->backend, I am able to find it but not sure how to connect back-end with Front end in this approach.

please help

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same and it took me a while to find out that the Logic App also needs to run under a "consumption plan":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-logic-app-as-api#prerequisites

When creating the Logic App you can chose between a Standard or Consuption plan.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem. I have a Logic App workflow defined as:
[image]

And yet this logic app does not show up when I attempt to import it into API Management:

[image]

The Logic App and API Management instances are in the same account and resource group.